# transporting roast beef

Tags: food-transport

I know how to roast beef in the correct way and let it rest before slicing, without wrapping it and making it sweat etc. etc.

My question is though that I'm roasting beef to take to a friends for dinner and I'm worried that after cooking if I transport it in a tupperware or something while warm, it will sweat and dry out and maybe even over cook. Do you think the best option after resting is to slice the entire thing and let it cool before transporting then just serving it cold at the other end?! Reheating the meat the other end will obviously over cook it...

Comment: How long must it be held before service (including the trip time)?  And how large is the roast?

Comment: I guess shortest time to serve is about 2hours. The roast is 1.4kg

Comment: Answered all my questions and as a results avoiding any stress related to traveling with this roast today!!! Merry Christmas my Christmas angels from 2013!!!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there's going to be some time between when it is cooked to when it is served, in which case the last thing you'd want to do is pre-carve it as it will dry out. Beef should rest after roasting, some chefs recommend roasting it as long as you cooked it, so don't worry if it takes 2-3 hours.

The important thing is to make sure you keep it warm and as moist as possible, so what I would do is wrap it in foil and put it in the bottom part of a tupperware container. The foil will keep it warm while the container will catch any drips. You can put the container at the bottom of a bag for transport, just keep the bag open. It's not going to overcook as long as you take it out 10-15 degrees F below the target temperature.

Just today I made a 2 rib roast and rested it by wrapping it in foil. The temperature climbed about 12 degrees after I took it out, and an hour and a half later it was still warmer than when I took it out of the oven, so the method works.

Comment: But immediately after cooking I want to 'tent' it in foil, right? Not wrap, as that will cause sweating, drying out & possibly over cooking..... So are you saying I should rest it first at home (what would be the minimum time?) and then 'wrap' in foil? And the tupperware should be lidded or not lidded? Thanks.

Comment: Or are you saying to bring it out of the oven early and wrap it immediately in foil to finish cooking?.... First problem, I don't have a thermometer! (I know I know I know I should but no time to get one now!).... So considering I was going to cook my 1.3kg roast for 1hr20mins @ 180c, how early would you recommend removal from the oven & wrapping? Thanks

Comment: You are correct, you take it out early and let it finish cooking while wrapped. No matter whether you wrap a roast or not it will finish cooking after you take it out. Wrapping it means that it will cook a bit more in the middle. I would say take it out 15 minutes early for a roast that size.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! I actually ended up taking the roast out 20mins early. I then wrapped it in 3 layers of foil & transported it in a well insulated but open Tupperware. Approximately an hour later I unwrapped the roast (which had expelled quite a bit of juice - worryingly) & let it rest in the open air but tented in foil for another 30mins or so..... I then carved it to find the most beautifully, perfectly & evenly cooked juicy medium pink flesh inside! It was absolutely perfect & everyone enjoyed it immensely! Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad it all came out well for you!